# Filtering R data frame for pareto optimal solutions

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe in R which is the result of the melt command:

```
"","compressed_size","variable","value"
"1",3.54257218819307,"ASD",734 
"2", 3.54761628976966,"ASD",676 
"3", 3.56890066825612,"ASD",684
"4", 3.80110901194377,"ASD",587 
"5", 3.66598964187419,"ASD",594
```

I would like to filter all dominated entries i.e. the ones where another entry exists that is equally good or better for compressed size and equally good or better for the value column. But strictly better for at least one. Better in this case means the value is smaller.

In the example above the third row would be dropped as the second row is better.

I am visualizing the data in a line plot using ggplot2, but am unaware of any functionality of ggplot2 that could be used.

I would also like to obtain pareto optimal solutions with more than two variables.

Comment: use the `rPref` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to Drey's comment I found the following answer:

```
p <- low(reverse_neighbors_time_comp)*low(compressed_size, df = dataframe)
peval(p)
```

The first line is the filter condition where `*` equals a pareto operator. For further information have a look at page 7 of:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPref/rPref.pdf